# How to validate that an argument is a positive number?

Tags: c

Although, I do define the function prototype as having a `size_t` type which is an unsigned type. I found that I can still pass negative numbers into the function, but the output will be a large signed decimal. The reason I ask this is because I want to validate an array index having known the array capacity.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void print(size_t i)
{
    printf("%zu\n", i);
}

int main()
{
    print(-1);

    return 0;
}
```

The output:
`18446744073709551615`

Is it possible to validate that the `size_t i` variable is greater than 0? If so how can I do this? gcc doesn't like me checking for `i >= 0` because it says that `i` can never be less than zero.

Edit:

For further explanation. Imagine that you have to validate than an arbitrary decimal is passed to a function to get an element at index i. I want to make sure that index passed in is within a boundary. That boundary is: [0, N)

Comment: You should get a compile time warning.  Make it an error.

Comment: There is no way to do that with `size_t` because the comparison will always be `true`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell This check must be performed at run time for my use case.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: It is a common technique to use `(size_t) -1` for `SIZE_MAX`, because `(size_t) -1` is more portable.  Enabling a warning here may have an unintended impact.  I know some compilers that do provide the warning (MSVC, I think) and others that don't (GCC, Clang, I think).

Comment: @self "This check must be performed at run time" and the example `print(-1);` are a contradiction as `-1` is evaluated at compile-time.  Maybe show a run-time example.

Comment: Just check that the value is not greater than a given threshhold such as `INT_MAX` or `RSIZE_MAX`.  The whole purpose of `rsize_t` in the *safer* functions invented by Microsoft is exactly your use case: take an unsigned value of type `size_t` but defensively check if some insanely huge number was passed, as would be the case of all negative numbers.

Comment: @chqelie how about `LONG_MAX` ?my object system uses 64 bit integers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C's type promotion system, combined with the fact that the type of the argument is `size_t`, an unsigned type, precludes there from being any way to detect the incorrect usage from inside the function. However you can detect it from outside via a macro:

```
#define print(x) do { if ((x)<0) { /* error */ } else print(x); } while(0)
```

or similar.

Comment: The macro can deal with literals only.

Comment: What if `x` some unsigned type? `((x)<0)` will never be true. Update: Oh, I see. Clever.

Comment: @EugeneSh. And the argument will not be negative in this case. Mission accomplished.

Comment: This is half, a good half, of OP's requested "boundary is: [0, N] (inclusive)"

Comment: I've got the right idea. I'm implementing a `CHECK_INDEX` macro that takes a bool as argument 2, and `i` as argument 1.

Comment: @PascalCuoq worth noting a compiler can rightfully bitch a phat warning about evaluation of a boolean expression that can never be false. If `x` is indeed an unsigned type `if ((x) < 0)` is ultimately worthless and the compiler may indeed tell you so.

Comment: @self: For your check against N, things are much simpler (in practice). Negative numbers reduced modulo `SIZE_MAX+1` will be larger than any achievable N, so simply checking `x>=N` solves your problem of catching invalid indices. But really you should just be using a proper type for the index in the caller (i.e. `size_t`, not a signed integer type).

Comment: @WhozCraig: That's harmful behavior by the compiler as far as I'm concerned, but we may have to agree to disagree on this.

Comment: @R.. There's nothing to disagree about, and I certainly have none with you. An unsigned type cannot be less than zero. An expression testing `(x) < 0` is therefore ultimately fruitless in the compiler's eyes if indeed `x` is an unsigned type. I was simply clarifying the point Eugene brought up (whether he realized it or not). Clang, for example, will yield "Comparision of unsigned expression < 0 is always false" if warnings are appropriately jacked.

Comment: @R.. Your note about `x>=N` seems to have solve the problem I am looking to solve.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Always-true and always-false expressions, even as controlling expressions, are valid in C, and they'll arise quite often out of macros. If you think this is bad, that's a matter of opinion, and that's what I said we'll have to agree to disagree on.

Comment: @R.. I guess I understand. I never claimed I was on the compiler's side on this either (though I usually am, obviously we all usually are). I was simply pointing out it can happen. How people feel about that is ultimately up to them, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually asking for a "reasonable" number check rather that negative number check (18446744073709551615 is indeed positive).

I could recommend comparing the size to some arbitrary limit such as 4 terabytes (4,398,046,511,104) (if it is indeed memory size).

If you indeed want to check for negative numbers, in gcc you can cast to `ssize_t` and then compare to 0.